# Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be an étale morphism of schemes. If $Y$ is integral, then is $X$ integral?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be an étale morphism of schemes.
We know:
    (1) if $Y$ is normal, then $X$ is normal.
    (2) if $Y$ is regular, then $X$ is regular.
    (3) if $Y$ is reduced, then $X$ is reduced.

> Question: If $Y$ is integral, then is $X$  integral?

Comment: This question would be more suitable on Math.SE. (Hint: the properties (1)-(3) are local, but integral isn't.)

Answer (score 8):

the answer is no for silly reasons: take X to be the disjoint union of two copies of Y.

Comment: right, I gave a somewhat more difficult example :-)

Comment: I think we were writing at the same time. Your answer is only testament to the fact that you're a proper algebraic geometer (where proper is meant in the non-technical sense -- you might not even be quasi-compact for all I know).

Comment: I would even have taken the sum of zero copies of $Y$.

Comment: @ACL: that is just superb! But wait, is Spec{0} not irreducible?

Comment: @user125763: No it's not! The empty topological space is not irreducible, but some say it is connected, and the zero ring is not integral.

Comment: [gasp!] -- ah, that's right, I always forget that (probably because I believe the empty set to be connected and I really believe it should also be irreducible!)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example where $X$ is not integral but connected.

Let $Y$ be the plane nodal curve $y^2=x^2(x+1)$. Then $Y$ admits an étale cover $f \colon X \to Y$ of degree $2$, where $X$ is the union of the two copies of the normalization of $Y$ (see [Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*], Exercise 10.6 page 276). These two components intersect in two points, both mapped to the node by $f$.

In particular $X$ is *not* an integral scheme, so the answer to your question is **no**.

Comment: Dear Francesco, this is a nice example, but $Y \sqcup Y \rightarrow Y$ (for any $Y$) seems a little simpler.

Comment: Dear Artie, of course you are completely right. I do not know why, but this was the first example that crossed my mind :-)

Comment: Dear Francesco, I envy your mental processes!

Comment: Well, missing trivial examples is not always so good :-)

Comment: Dear Francesco and Artie, Thank you for nice examples.

Comment: $X$ is not a disjoint union; it has a single connected component, but two irreducible components.

Comment: @Ben:of course you are right (actually, this is what makes this example interesting). I corrected the answer, thank you.